# Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rentalmobil\resources\views\admin\user.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5, undefined

## SOLVED

i am confusing that i think i have already make a true code with laravel. i have seen on many references for me to know how to read database. yes i'm newbie and still learning. well here is my code

from model. admin.php is the name of folder:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    protected $table = "admin";
}
```

here is my controller. my controller name is UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Admin;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function users(){
        $users = Admin::all();
        return view('admin.user', ['admin' => $users]);
    }

}
```

and here is my view, it is located in view/admin/ named user.blade.php:

```
@extends('admin.header')

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title">Striped Table</h4>
            <p class="category">Here is a subtitle for this table</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>{{ $users->email }}</td>
                        <td>$36,738</td>
                        <td>Niger</td>
                        <td>Oud-Turnhout</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and here is my error

i call from my browser with this http://localhost:8000/users

[image: image description]

sorry for bad English :(

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, try to copy/paste the error text. That will make easier for others to search for similar issues, and to quote if necessary when answering this question

Comment: variable for blade is $admin not $users. Add a loop also for $admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach($admin as $users) 
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>{{ $users->email }}</td>
                        <td>$36,738</td>
                        <td>Niger</td>
                        <td>Oud-Turnhout</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
@endforeach
```

if u not need for each

```
             <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>{{ $admin[0]->email }}</td>
                            <td>$36,738</td>
                            <td>Niger</td>
                            <td>Oud-Turnhout</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable will be called `admin` in the view, because that's how you passed it when you wrote `'admin' => $users`.

Second, it's going to be a *collection* of users, so `$users->email` isn't going to work. You need to `@foreach` through *each* user.

Comment: Third, your admins should *typically* just be normal `App\User` objects with an admin flag or role or something. Not a totally separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `view/admin/user.blade.php` and `UserController`  like:

**UserController**:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function users(){
        $users = Admin::all();
        return view('admin.user', compact('users'));
    }

}
```

**view/admin/user.blade.php**:

```
<tbody>

 @foreach($users as $user)
   <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
       <td>$36,738</td>
       <td>Niger</td>
       <td>Oud-Turnhout</td>
   </tr>                
</tbody>
```